# How to count distinct duplicate characters in a string

Tags: php

I have a string "Bbcdefcgh!!" and I want to count the distinct duplicate characters. The solution should consider upper and lower case characters as distinct characters and also deal with the alphaneumeric and special characters.

For example: Given a string "Bbcdefcgh!!" the function should return 2 ('c' and '!')

```
class DuplicateChar
{

    public function test1() 
    {
       return $this->duplicateCharacters("Bbcdefcgh!!");    
    }

    public function duplicateCharacters($input)
    {
      //
    }
}

 $o = new DuplicateChar;
 echo $o->test1();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a few cool functions here:

```
$str = 'Bbcdefcgh!!';
$arr = str_split($str);

$data = array_filter(array_count_values($arr), function($el)
{
    return ($el > 1);
});

echo '<pre>'. print_r($data, 1) .'</pre>';
```

we use `str_split` to split the string into an array, we then filter the values using `array_count_filter` to only get items with more than 1 dupe.

refs:

- [str_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)
- [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)
- [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

**Edit: using count_chars**

As pointed out by NigelRen, this can be done using `count_chars()`:

> count_chars — Return information about characters used in a string

```
$data = "Two Ts and one F.";

foreach (count_chars($data, 1) as $i => $val)
{
   echo "There were $val instance(s) of \"" , chr($i) , "\" in the string.\n";
}
```

[full docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php#refsect1-function.count-chars-examples)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_split` and `array_count_values` to approach this

```
$str = 'Bbcdefcgh!!';
$textToArray = str_split($str);
echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_count_values($textToArray));
```

Result

```
Array
(
[B] => 1
[b] => 1
[c] => 2
[d] => 1
[e] => 1
[f] => 1
[g] => 1
[h] => 1
[!] => 2
)
```